# Transfer matrix eigenvalue exponential

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Let us define the one-dimensional transfer matrix in quantum mechanics
\begin{align}
 M=\begin{pmatrix}
  1/t^*&-r^*/t^*\\
  -r/t & 1/t
 \end{pmatrix}\,,
\end{align}
where $r$ and $t$ are the incident reflection and transmission coefficients. Because the similarity transformation of the transfer matrix $M^\dagger\sigma_z M=\sigma_z$, where $\sigma_z=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & -1
 \end{pmatrix}$, holds, then, according to [Delande and Müller](https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.0915) (see exercise 2 *(iv)*), it is possible to show

1. $M^\dagger M$ and $\left(M^\dagger M\right)^{-1}$ share the same eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}$ given by
   \begin{align}
   \lambda_{1,2}=\frac{\left(1\pm|r|\right)^2}{|t|^2}\in\mathbb{R}\,.
   \end{align}
2. After a direct computation with the above result, it is possible to prove $\lambda_1\lambda_2=1$.
3. Here is my question: "Since these eigenvalues must also be each other’s inverses, they can only be of the form $\lambda_1=1/\lambda_2=e^{2x}$". How on earth can I obtain $\lambda_1=e^{2x}$ and $\lambda_2=e^{-2x}$?

Comment: What is $x$ supposed to be? Isn’t it just defined to make $\lambda_1=e^{2x}$, for some reason that you haven’t explained?

Comment: ...the reason is that we could have a simple expression for the transmission coefficient  (see exercise 2 (v)) : Thus, the total transmission probability is $\;T = 1/\cosh^2x\;$.

Comment: @Frobenius, well, in the article seems that was possible to deduce $\lambda_1=e^{2x}$ and $\lambda_2=e^{-2x}$, so now I understand it is a convenient choice.

Thanks for the clarification!